# How to apply an ffmpeg filter to a moving object?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a video in which I want to blur out a part of every frame (face). I have the coordinates for the face bounding box and these could change with every frame.

After digging through the documentation, I have understood that the way to do this is to apply a chain of filters

- Crop filter to crop out the part
- Blur the cropped video
- Overlay the cropped and blurred video in the original location

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]crop=200:200:60:30[cropped];[cropped]avgblur=10[croppedblurred];[0][croppedblurred]overlay=60:30" output_video.mp4
```

This works well for bounding box coordinates that do not change through the video. How can I do this for bounding boxes locations that could change with every frame?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the timestamps you can use `trim` filter to set the chain of needed filters for specific duration in the input video. The example below sets three different chains of filters every 10 seconds. All you need to remember is to use different names in `[ ]` for every step of `-filter_complex`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex ^
 ^"[0:v]trim=start=0:end=10[a]; ^
   [0:v]trim=start=10:end=20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; ^
   [0:v]trim=start=20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[c]; ^
   [a] here insert your chain of filters for this part of video [aa]; ^
   [b] here insert your chain of filters for this part of video [bb]; ^
   [c] here insert your chain of filters for this part of video [cc]; ^
   [aa][bb]concat[aaa]; ^
   [aaa][cc]concat[video]^" ^
 -map [video]:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: This approach works great! I'm using frame numbers so I have replaced start with start_frame and end with end_frame. But this approach seems to be failing if the bounding box changes on every frame. In those cases, the logs show that most of the frames are being dropped
dup=0 drop=597 speed=3.25e-06x 

Any pointers on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's practical to solve it "manually" (without programming).
In theory, we can use [Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Expression-Evaluation) for setting the `x` and `y` coordinates according to the frame number or frame time.

---

Building synthetic pattern (for demonstration):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 10 -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=300 -vf setpts=N/10/TB -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 17 input_video.mp4
```

---

Example for positioning the blurred area according to frame number:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input_video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]avgblur=10,crop=50:50:'if(lte(n,100), n+10, if(lte(n,200), 210-n, 10))':'if(gte(n,100), 5+(n-100)/5, 5)'[blurredcropped];[0][blurredcropped]overlay='if(lte(n,100), n+10, if(lte(n,200), 210-n, 10))':'if(gte(n,100), 5+(n-100)/5, 5)':format=yuv444" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 17 output_video.mp4
```

---

Sample output (converted to animated gif):
[image]